# CPU accounting not working for services assigned to isolated core

Tags: systemd

I am setting up CPU accounting on some services, and noticed that a few of them are not reporting CPU usage correctly.
It seems that the services that are not reporting any usage are the ones that are assigned via `CPUAffinity` to only run on a core that I have isolated at the kernel level using the `isolcpus` kernel argument.

Here is an example snippet of the status of such a service:

```
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system.control/gnss.service.d
             └─50-CPUAccounting.conf, 50-MemoryAccounting.conf
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-12-15 22:31:10 UTC; 2 days ago
   Main PID: 1233 (quectel_lg69t_g)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 8479)
     Memory: 3.7M
        CPU: 0
     CGroup: /system.slice/gnss.service
```

while another service from the same system is reporting usage correctly:

```
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system.control/cameras.service.d
             └─50-CPUAccounting.conf, 50-MemoryAccounting.conf
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-12-18 17:29:43 UTC; 1s ago
   Main PID: 3253648 (cameras)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 8479)
     Memory: 3.7M
        CPU: 27ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/cameras.service
```

I can see the service using CPU in `htop`, so I am certain it isn't just idle/frozen and actually not using any CPU.

I assume this must be due to a side effect of core isolation, but I am not sure where to start here. Maybe systemd needs something running on the isolated core in order to track CPU time usage of tasks that get assigned there?

In researching this I also discovered that `isolcpus` may be deprecated, and that I should be using `cpuset` instead. I am going to play around with this, but it also sounds like `cpuset`s leaves the scheduler enabled on the isolated core, which I do not want as I am aiming for a realtime-like setup for the isolated core with as few interrupts as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out why this doesn't work through trial and error.

It turned out that the real cause of the problem was that the isolated services used a realtime `fifo` scheduler, and enabling systemd CPU accounting on services with that scheduler does not appear to be possible.
More specifically, it will appear to be enabled, but just not functional, when in reality the service is now in a bad state. If you try to restart it, you get hit with an error, specifically the one described in [this Red Hat article.](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2860951)